# Verify for the text to be present in an overlay using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I have an overlay form where i create an user for our application. After giving the details in the text fields i click on save and try to capture the Saved Successfully Text which appears for about a second on the overlay. But i am unable to do so as i get an error saying `"Element is no longer attached to the DOM (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)"`.
**I have used the below code:**

```
if($browser.div(:class=>"validation-summary-valid").exists?)
   message=$browser.div(:class=>"validation-summary-valid").li.text
   if(message=="Saved Sucessfully")
     puts("Save action complete")
    else
     fail("fail")       
   end 
end
```

Comment: Trying to verify something that is transient might not be a good idea. Depending on timings, you could end up with random failures. I would suggest you test for something static instead.

Answer (score 0):

in capybara i would scope the code using ( within ) to the message element in the Dom then use have_content

```
within('#Browser div')do 
page.should have_content('Saved Successfully') 
end
```

hope this will help to try something similar in watir

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from the situation is, the moment you click on save a transient message appears on the UI and a check needs to be performed.

The below approach should work fine in this case,

```
# the browser waits for 20 s until the element is present(exists+visible) on the UI
$browser.div(:class=>"validation-summary-valid").wait_until_present(20).li.text
```